# jquery select parent not child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select parent div not child, how do I do this in jQuery.
Basically I want to create a simple login box, it should hide if and only if I click on parent div, if I click on child div the box should not hide.
Below is the code.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        jQuery("li.login-link").click(function ()
        {
            jQuery("div#login-container").css("display", "block");
        });
        jQuery("div#login-container not:(div#login-box)").click(function ()
        {
            jQuery("div#login-container").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="login-container"> <!--parent div. Should hide when i click on this div-->
    <div id="login-box"> <!--child div. Should not hide parent when i click on this-->
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean... since you have an id... use that to select the element

Comment: my requirement is, when i click the div#login-container it will be hide, not on the click event of the child(#login-box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.parent()`: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$('div#login-box').parent()
```

or

```
$('div#login-box').parent('div#login-container')
```

**Edit**

As per your comment below, I think you are after stop propagation: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
//hide the box when you click the parent:
$('div#login-container').click(function() { $(this).hide() });

// stop child click bubbling up to parent
$('div#login-box').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: actually i want to hide the login-container only when parent(div#login-container) is clicked not the child(div#login-box) click event

Answer (score 0):

check this one

HTML :

```
<div id="login-container">
    <div id="login-box">
        Hi
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$("div#login-box").click(function ()
 {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color","red")
     console.log()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#login-container").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#login-box').length) {
      $("div#login-container").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#login-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
#login-box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login-container">
  <div id="login-box">

  </div>
</div>
```